# Call resolve() explicitly in .then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

If I create a new promise object and return a new promise object inside like this, p1 will keep pending.

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(1);
    });
});
```

But if I chain the inner new promise with a then() and call revolve, the outer new promise p1 will get resolved.

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(1);
    }).then(data => resolve(123));
});
```

It seems that the `resolve()` in the `.then()` actually resolve p1. Can anyone tell me what is happening here? Why can't the first p1 be resolved and why the second p1 is resolved?

Comment: I think the outer promise is redundant.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this nesting? There's probably a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise `p1` in the second snippet gets resolved as the `resolve` inside the `then` callback is referring to the `resolve` passed in the callback of the *outer* `Promise` constructor and not to the `resolve` of the inner `Promise` constructor.

In the first snippet, the `resolve` is always referring to the `resolve` of the inner `Promise` constructor and hence the outer Promise never gets resolved.

Just rename the callbacks and check:

```js
var p1 = new Promise((outerResolve, reject) => {
  return new Promise((innerResolve, reject) => {
      //resolve of inner
      return innerResolve(1);
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      //Resolve of outer
      outerResolve(123);
    });
});

p1.then(console.log)
```

The outer promise in the first snippet `p1` will never resolve as its `resolve` is never called. it will always be in the `pending` state.

Answer (score 3):

You're shadowing the argument `resolve` in the first example. Try:

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve1, reject1) => {
  resolve1(new Promise((resolve2, reject2) => {
    resolve2(1);
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the promise executor function (the function you pass to `new Promise`) is completely ignored; it has no meaning. Returning a promise from it doesn't do anything. Also, as [fodma1 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283413/157247), you're calling the inner promise's `resolve`, not the outer one.

Your second form uses a fulfillment handler on the inner promise to fulfill the outer one. While you *can* do that, and perhaps sometimes it's appropriate, in the usual case you'd just use the inner promise directly and do the other work in the `then` callback.